# Syntax highlighting for Excel Formulae - language suggestions

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Based on most popular answer:

> Tl;dr: to use the Swift language rules, add `<!-- language-all: lang-swift -->` to the top of your post, or use  ```` ```lang-swift ```` at the beginning of each code block where you desire highlighting.

---

Highlight.js doesn't support the Excel formula language and I doubt SE would add it to the list of styles to support on the network. This has been [asked for at Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418984/add-default-syntax-highlighting-for-excel-formula-tag) too.

What's a good alternative?

For example this code:

```
=LAMBDA
(
  vArg,
  LET
  (
    v,    INT(ABS(vArg)),
    ev,   ISEVEN(v),
    half, 1/2,
    high, INT(SQRT(v)+half),
    seqLimit, 2^20,
    IF
    (
      AND(ev, v<>2),
      0, 
      IF
      (
        high>seqLimit,
        -1, 
        LET
        (
          high,         INT(SQRT(v)+1/2),
          seq,          v/SEQUENCE(1,high,1,2),
          iSeq,         INT(seq),
          factors,      seq*(seq=iSeq),
          rFactors,     FILTER(factors,(factors>1)*(factors<v),0),
          sumFactors,   SUM(rFactors)
          --(sumFactors=0) 
        )
      ) 
    )
  )
)
```

is rendered using the tag based ([excel](/questions/tagged/excel) or [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda)) or auto recognition syntax highlighting like this:

[image: Rendered code]
which is not perfect as the `--(sumFactors=0)` line is rendered like a comment to me which is wrong, and formula names `ISEVEN`, `FILTER` etc. are highlighted inconsistently.

Any suggestions of similar supported languages that may look good?

Comment: This doesn't look like anything Inwould put in an excel cell.

Comment: @Luuklag I just found this[LAMBDA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67). It suggest to add the formula in a cell to test it before add it to the name manager.

Comment: @Luuklag, it's a new (beta channel) function so you may not have seen it before but it's nothing special, identical syntax to the more vanilla functions. Just been through a formula prettifier, but whitespace doesn't matter to Excel

Comment: @Greedo What tool do you use to format your formulas?

Comment: @JimGrisham https://www.excelformulabeautifier.com/

Answer (score 6):

Try using Scala (`lang-scala`)

Example:

```scala
=LAMBDA
(
  vArg,
  LET
  (
    v,    INT(ABS(vArg)),
    ev,   ISEVEN(v),
    half, 1/2,
    high, INT(SQRT(v)+half),
    seqLimit, 2^20,
    IF
    (
      AND(ev, v<>2),
      0, 
      IF
      (
        high>seqLimit,
        -1, 
        LET
        (
          high,         INT(SQRT(v)+1/2),
          seq,          v/SEQUENCE(1,high,1,2),
          iSeq,         INT(seq),
          factors,      seq*(seq=iSeq),
          rFactors,     FILTER(factors,(factors>1)*(factors<v),0),
          sumFactors,   SUM(rFactors)
          --(sumFactors=0) 
        )
      ) 
    )
  )
)
```

As far as I can tell, this works well with minified formula.

Example for minified formula:

```scala
=LET(hello,"Hello World, ",hello & Sheet1!$A2 & "!")
```

Comment: *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)*

Answer (score 4):

Try `swift`

```swift
=IF($A1>6,"Hello","Goodbye")
```

---

```swift
=LAMBDA
(
  vArg,
  LET
  (
    v,    INT(ABS(vArg)),
    ev,   ISEVEN(v),
    half, 1/2,
    high, INT(SQRT(v)+half),
    seqLimit, 2^20,
    IF
    (
      AND(ev, v<>2),
      0, 
      IF
      (
        high>seqLimit,
        -1, 
        LET
        (
          high,         INT(SQRT(v)+1/2),
          seq,          v/SEQUENCE(1,high,1,2),
          iSeq,         INT(seq),
          factors,      seq*(seq=iSeq),
          rFactors,     FILTER(factors,(factors>1)*(factors<v),0),
          sumFactors,   SUM(rFactors),
          --(sumFactors=0) 
        )
      ) 
    )
  )
)
```

---

highlight.js actually supports Excel (ref: [Supported Languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md)) but it's not supported by the highlighter version of SE.

I'm not familiar with Excel Lambda functions but it looks that the problem is the formula, not the highlighting. I.E, the following formula taken from [another post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80405/91556) from Code Review, the highlight is applied correctly there

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(X2),ISBLANK(Y2)),0,X2/VLOOKUP(YEAR(Y2),$EU$3:$FH$57,14,FALSE))*$FH$57
```

Rendered version of the above formula taken from the source

[image]

NOTE: Using the inspect tool, the auto-detect function assigned `swift` to the above formula and `sql` to the formula in the question.

I just quickly scanned [LAMBDA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67). As far I can tell, it looks that the Lambda function in the question is not using the regular spreadsheet formula syntax as there is no separator before `--(sumFactors=0)`. But that is not the unique problem b/c after adding the comma, Excel still shows:

[image]

P.S. looking at the source of the formula the OP mentioned that the formula doesn't work.

Related

- [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/289691)

Comment: Oh yeah, there should be a comma, it's not my code - I got it from here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257331/146810. But I tried editing the question to add the comma and it still renderers wrong. Besides the inconsistent formula name highlighting is a bigger problem for readability.

Comment: @Greedo Please consider to add a better formula example

Comment: Unfortunately not imported by SO: https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js does not reference any of the tags for excel/xls/xlsx (point 3 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/354801)). As for the formula, it's very new beta channel so may not be available to you, and requires an additional set of parens `=LAMBDA(...)(...)` to invoke it. But my question with correct syntax is highlighted wrong: [ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972338/6609896) ], [ [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253549/146810) ]. I like the example you give, different language tag maybe?

Comment: Thanks, swift looks good, even though its syntax looks totally different to Excel formulae, strange! I'll leave this unaccepted in case someone finds an even nicer looking highlighting tag

Comment: Thanks -- setting the language as Swift works _great_ in both VSCode and Notepad++ (and likely other editors with Swift support)!

Comment: Tl;dr: to use the Swift language rules on StackExchange, add "<!-- language-all: lang-swift -->" to the top of your post, or use "``` lang-swift" at the beginning of each code block where you desire highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

Adding syntax highlighting for Excel Formula would be a good thing.  Ideally it would be specific to Excel formula (ie as supported by highlight.js), however if that's unlikely to be supported on SO/SE then utilising another language would be acceptable.  The question is: which one.

Whichever is chosen, it should

- give useful highlights to the various components of a formula
- give reasonable results on most (if not all) common use cases
- give unhelpful results on as few as possible edge cases

The two suggested languages are compared below

Swift

```swift
=A1+A2
=$A$1+A2
=A$1+A4
=$A1+A5
=$A$1:A10+B10:B100
=SUM(A1:A10)
=SUM(R1C1:R[9]C1+RC[-3]:RC[-3])
=MyRange
=MyUDF(A1:A10,B1,"Hi",-C1+D1,MyRange)
=D1#
=@D1
=@D1:D100
=XLOOKUP(J1,H1:H10,D1:D10,"A1",0,1)
=--(A1:A10=0)
=IF($A1>6,"Hello","Goodbye")
=LAMBDA(base,width,paddingStr, IF(LEN(base)<=width, base, LET(LHS, LEFT(base, width), RHS, RIGHT(base, LEN(base) - width), LHS & paddingStr & PadInternal(RHS,width,paddingStr))))
```

Scala

```scala
=A1+A2
=$A$1+A2
=A$1+A4
=$A1+A5
=$A$1:A10+B10:B100
=SUM(A1:A10)
=SUM(R1C1:R[9]C[-4]+RC[-3]:R[9]C[-3])
=MyRange
=MyUDF(A1:A10,B1,"Hi",-C1+D1,MyRange)
=D1#
=@D1
=@D1:D100
=XLOOKUP(J1,H1:H10,D1:D10,"A1",0,1)
=--(A1:A10=0)
=IF($A1>6,"Hello","Goodbye")
=LAMBDA(base,width,paddingStr, IF(LEN(base)<=width, base, LET(LHS, LEFT(base, width), RHS, RIGHT(base, LEN(base) - width), LHS & paddingStr & PadInternal(RHS,width,paddingStr))))
```

Based on this, I'd suggest Swift be ruled out, as it gives inconsistent results for range references, and mangles *some* ranges.

Scala is better, but doesn't handle Implicit Intersection ranges well

Comment: This is Community Wiki so anyone can add more example formula and/or languages.

Comment: Some more edge cases; linebreaks, various operators like `/` which might trip it up, table references